# Displaying a subView in didReceiveRemoteNotification?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

What Im trying to do is displaying my subView in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` when the app receives a notification and is running. How can I do this?

My code right now in didReceiveRemoteNotification:

```
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        AcceptAlertViewCreator *acceptAlertViewCreator = [[AcceptAlertViewCreator alloc] init];
        //Here I try to get the current viewController running...
        UIViewController *viewController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];
        //This line gives me the "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17816b7c0" error
        [viewController.view addSubview:[acceptAlertViewCreator createAlertViewWithViewController:viewController andText:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"message"]]];
    }
    else
    {
        //other things
    }
```

My `AcceptAlertViewCreator` returns a `UIView` and gets a `viewController` for the `viewController` to be displayed in and `NSString` for message. My AcceptAlertViewCreator also has a `UIViewAnimation` when it is played.

My `AcceptAlertViewCreator` works great when added to a normal `ViewController` `subView`.

Anyone knows how I can accomplish this? Id doesn't have to be adding a subView. It could be a workaround in some ways, or please give me some pointers. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting the `viewController` from `sharedApplication` just get the `rootViewController` of you `window`

You `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method should look like this:

```
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
{
    AcceptAlertViewCreator *acceptAlertViewCreator = [[AcceptAlertViewCreator alloc] init];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:[acceptAlertViewCreator createAlertViewWithViewController:self.window.rootViewController andText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"message"]]]];
}
else
{
    //other things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are having your AppDelegate display a window when an alert comes in.

I would not add it as a subview, I would just present the view controller instead. I assume you want some action to be taken when this notice comes in.

You could also use NSNotificationCenter to send a notification to your app when the push notification comes in. You trigger the NSNotification from didReceiveRemoteNotification and your app views would need to listen for this notifications. The downside is each view would need to listen for this notification.